# Need to find partnering rows and if non-exsist delete row

Tags: excel, vba, matching

[image]

• Read row starting at 2 and get column d
• check column A on that row and if it is 4610* get Column B value
• now read through a rows and if has the same value as previous column d check column a value
• if new row column a equals 480* or 490* check that rows column B value
• if new column B value is = abs(old column b value) it’s all good. Keep those rows 
• if colmun d  only has one value 4610* or 480* or 490* with no matching counterpart delete it

Hopefully that is better. Basically I need the unique number in column d to have two entries
• one a value of 4610* in column a with a negative value 
•the other a 480 or 490 with a value in column b that equals the abs of 4610 value

Basically it’s kinda like a check book only I run through hundreds of thousands of transactions and that are sent in these sheets. I even tried looking up the VBA to kinda make a checkbook which is how I got rid of all the data that I absolutely don’t need. Hopefully that makes more sense. For every 4610 if there is a matching 480 or 490 I care and need to keep both but if it’s only one or the other I don’t need the information

So in some spots it’s a sometimes a from 490 to a 490 and they share a doc num but those two wouldn’t matter to me so those can be deleted

I'm trying to use VBA and I'm a noob, but I've managed to take an extremely large data set and remove all of the rows I absolutely don't need.  Now I'm trying to figure out the vba code that will allow me finish removing the rest of the data that isn't used.  I'm putting a screen shot but basically in column d I have a doc no.  I need to look through all the rows and if column a is 4610.* I need to have a matching value for the same doc num in column a of 480* or 490* and the column b 4610* values must be negative and the corresponding doc no for the 480* and 490* account needs to be the = to the abs of that negative number.

If either the doc no. has a 4610.* in column a but no matching 480* or 490* number in the column a then I need to delete that row.  and vice versa if there is a 480* or 490* in column a without a corresponding 4610.* in column a for the same doc no value in column d then I need to delete those.  This is the home stretch and I can't figure out anything that will work.  I did find an awesome way to create infinite loops.   I greatly appreciate any help.  Thank you.

I attached all the code that I have made so far.  I'm trying to put this new process in the DataMatch sub.  This is my first time messing with VBA so it's been interesting hmmmmmmmm.  Thanks again.

```
Option Explicit

   Sub CleanUpData()
   'Prepare Excel for macro to run
     Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
   Application.EnableEvents = False
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Call InitialDataClean
    Call SecondDataScrub
    Call DataMatch
    'Call RemoveBlanks

   'Return Excel to Status prior to Macro
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
   Application.EnableEvents = True
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   End Sub
   Sub DataMatch()

   End Sub

   Sub RemoveBlanks()

    'Declare the variables
    Dim deleteRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet


    'Set Objects & declare known variables
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
        'Loop through the rows of data, in order to delete row matching desired variables
        For deleteRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        If ws.Range("A" & deleteRow).Text = "" Then
        Rows(deleteRow).EntireRow.ClearFormats
        Rows(deleteRow).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
        Next deleteRow


End Sub



Sub SecondDataScrub()


    'Declare the variables
    Dim deleteRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim myCriteria2 As String
    Dim myCriteria3 As String

    'Set Objects & declare known variables
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    myCriteria2 = "*480*"
    myCriteria3 = "*490*"

        'Loop through the rows of data, in order to delete row matching desired variables
        For deleteRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1

        'Initial removal of unneeded data
        If ws.Range("A" & deleteRow).Text Like myCriteria2 And ws.Range("b" & deleteRow).Value < 0 Then
        Rows(deleteRow).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
        If ws.Range("A" & deleteRow).Text Like myCriteria3 And ws.Range("b" & deleteRow).Value < 0 Then
        Rows(deleteRow).EntireRow.Delete
        End If

      Next deleteRow



End Sub


Sub InitialDataClean()


    'Declare the variables
    Dim deleteRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim myCriteria As String
    Dim myCriteria2 As String
    Dim myCriteria3 As String

    'Set Objects & declare known variables
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    myCriteria = "*4610.*"
    myCriteria2 = "*4700.*"
    myCriteria3 = "*4871.*"

        'Loop through the rows of data, in order to delete row matching desired variables
        For deleteRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1

        'Initial removal of unneeded data
        If ws.Range("A" & deleteRow).Text Like myCriteria And ws.Range("B" & deleteRow).Value >= 0 Then
        Rows(deleteRow).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
        'If ws.Range("A" & deleteRow).Text = "" Then
        'Rows(deleteRow).EntireRow.ClearFormats
        'Rows(deleteRow).EntireRow.Delete
        'End If
        If ws.Range("A" & deleteRow).Text Like myCriteria2 Then
        Rows(deleteRow).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
        If ws.Range("A" & deleteRow).Text Like myCriteria3 Then
        Rows(deleteRow).EntireRow.Delete
        End If

      Next deleteRow


End Sub


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgezp.png
```

Comment: Your question if very confusing. Do you think you can bullet point out the criteria you are trying to get to?

Answer (score 0):

If I get your post right your logic is:

- read Doc. no. in Column D by row
- if Doc. no. is empty delete entire row (get rid of all rows that only have a doc. no. in Column E)
- check if first 3 digits of Column A in same row are "460", "480" or "490"
- if No: Delete entire row
- if Yes: check if exactly one other cell in Column D has the same Doc. no.
- if No: Delete entire row
- if Yes: Check if absolute amount in Column B is identical between Cell (Workrow, D) and cell (matching Doc. no. cell row, D)
- if No: delete both rows
- if Yes: take no action (keep both rows)

Is that logic correct? Can the rows be sorted by Column D or does the order have to be preserved?

Comment: I added it to the original post. I’ll have to pretty it up when I get home. Stupid iPhone typing is a pain but thank you

Comment: What about those lines with no value in A:D - can those be deleted?  Is there anything that forbids sorting by column D?

Comment: The lines that are blank I can get to delete with that DeleteBlanks sub. I just didn’t run that part for the picture because I thought it showed the data a little better.  It could be sorted on column D and that would be fine. Ideally i will get it to the point I will go straight down the list and the doc no will be together the 4601 on the top the 480* or 490* associated with it right below it.